# check if file has been uploaded by user in a form

Tags: php

I have a form where multiple images can be selected...

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-field" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple accept="image/*" class="form-field">
    <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" class="button" name="submit4">
</form>
```

Then, in my PHP I want to detect if at least 1 file has been uploaded.... I tried this, but the code still triggers as if a file was uploaded...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit4']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
   echo "post sucessful<br>";

     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['temp_name']))
        { echo "file exist";}
    else{ echo "no file";}

}
```

THIS always triggers the "no file" even if there is a file..

and if I try:

```
 if(!empty($_FILES['files']['temp_name']))
```

it always triggers the "no file" ... I'm really confused...

Comment: Take a look at the PHP documentation for the [`is_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file) function. You'll want to pass in the `tmp_name` instead of the `name`.

Comment: @kstev can you please re-check this problem, i've updated the page with the problem it's giving me... the is_uploaded_file doesn't work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
      if(!file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo  "No File";
    }
else{

echo "Successfully uploaded";
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention [the source of the code you are copying verbatim](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file). Additionally, this does not help the OP as they want to check to see if any files at all were uploaded.

Comment: can you please recheck this problem, i've updated my code with problem it's giving me... thx

Comment: You need to check the folder permissions

Comment: the permission is 777, if I simply take out the check, I can upload the file just fine on my server, so it's not a permission problem

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer...

```
if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0]))
```

works quit well... thanks everyone.